How to return a value based on value from two column vis excel?
Excel table

I want to return a value in another column based on two columns.  For E.g i want the funtion to return "low" for the " IntAct_percent" under the KPI Column if the value is less that 1 , The value for IntAct_percent now shows" 0.68205xxx , therefore the function should return "low"" in another column. How do it do it  ?
i have tried if else function , filter to gether with if else ,but still cant.
Excel table after apply the function


IF should work. Please show us the formula you have tried.

=IF(AND([@KPI]="IntAct",[@Value]>60), "High","low")   , this is the formula used.  i have attached new snapshot where it just return low for all. so I guess it find everything is false

Maybe there are inivisible characters at the end of the KPI members. Try to TRIM([@KPI])

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try changing your formula as follows:
=IF(AND(CLEAN(TRIM([@KPI]))="IntAct",NUMBERVALUE([@Value])>60), "High","low")

CLEAN() removes non-printing characters, TRIM() removes leading and trailing spaces, and NUMBERVALUE() coerces string numerals to numbers.
